# How to print a particular installed conda package version number exit?

Tags: conda

I want to print only the version number of a particular package on terminal prefixing its name.

Something like this but for individual conda packages:

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.6.14
```

Is there any built in functions that I'm not aware?

Comment: What do you want to do with this information? If we know that, it can help specify the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

`conda list` is probably what you are looking for? with a prefix you can just `grep` it.

```
conda list | grep ^ala
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
```

```
conda list | grep ^pytest
pytest                    4.0.2                    py37_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.3              py37h39e3cac_0
pytest-astropy            0.5.0                    py37_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.2.0                    py37_0
pytest-openfiles          0.3.1                    py37_0
pytest-remotedata         0.3.1                    py37_0
```

Comment: No this I know. I want a particular conda package version to be printed. Something like ```alabaster 0.7.12 ```. Not this table.

Comment: @sksahu - just updated my answer, not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for, but it works if you want specific packages with a prefix, hope it helps.